# Print response JSON from server with HTTP POST

Tags: python, json, http, python-3.x, post

How can I get respon JSON dictionaries from server with POST:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://apiurl.com'        
parameters = {'code':1,
              'user': 'username',
              'password': 'password'
              }

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'} 
response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(parameters),headers=headers)
print(response)
```

> output: Response [200]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(parameters), headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: <Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barry/Documents/Project/treeview.py", line 31, in <module>
    test2()
  File "/home/barry/Documents/Project/treeview.py", line 27, in test2
    print (response.txt)
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'txt'

Comment: @BarryVassyah - it is `print(response.text)` and **not** `print(response.txt)`. Please check the spelling.

Comment: Have you tried response.text ? It seems you have miscoded it as response.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are going to receive a JSON object you can simply use [request's built-in JSON decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) Simply do:

```
j = response.json()
```

Comment: i got erorr : ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @BarryVassyah - I guess, you'll face an issue converting `response.text` to a _parse-able_  JSON object. Let me know if you face an issue.